# Convert epoch into datetime in CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, datetime, cloudpage

I have a CloudPage JS Resource that I use to parse a JSON. As part of the JSON, a UTC timestamp in milliseconds is provided. I want to convert that into a DateTime and save it in a DE. I've tried doing that with *new Date()*, but instead of the UTC time, the CST time is saved in the DE.

This is the code I'm using

```
var timestamp = new Date(json[0].timestampUTC);
```

As an example, when I receive this

> "timestampUTC":1698238714220

in the DE the following date was added

[image]

even though it was 12:58 UTC time.

Worth mentioning that I have the Account and the User on London time, not CST time.

How can I save this Datetime value in a DE as UTC time instead of CST time?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this `timestampUTC` value is formatted?

Comment: Added an exemple

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Cloud servers use the Central Standard Time (CST) Time Zone, but do not observe Daylight Savings Time (DST).

> Systems will remain on Central Standard Time (CST) and will not change to (or from) Central Daylight Time (CDT) in March and November, respectively.
>
> Systems will *ALWAYS* be -0600 from GMT at all times of the year.

Reference: [Marketing Cloud Server Time Zone Changes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384850&type=1)

In order to have your expected time zone, you can try something like this:

```
var timestamp = new Date(json[0].timestampUTC);
// Convert to London time
    timestamp.setHours(timestamp.getHours() + 7); // increased 7 hours
```

But I would recommend you keep the CST time value in the DE. If you use the DE to send comms to your customers, you can covert it later by AMPscript.

Comment: I know I can add hours to get the UTC time (+6), but why is it in CST timezone when I'm giving it a value? I'm not using Date() without parameters, I'm giving the function something that I want to turn into a date. If I'm using ```new Date('2023-10-25T12:58:00');``` it will save 12:58 (the UTC time) in the DE or 06:58 (the CST time)?

Comment: @Alex The reason for this is that the MC system always considers the input time value is UTC +0 and turn it into the its system time UTC-6